# Does XML Spec define that it is illegal to have whitespace before self closing slash?

Tags: xml

I am talking XML document not HTML. Since in HTML, `<br/>` and `<br />` are both valid.
Want to know if XML specification defines whether it is allowed to have whitespace before the self closing slash? I just encountered a odd problem that `<something />` doesn't work when i use other's library.

Answer (score 4):

The space at the end is allowed for "normal" tags as well as for empty elements, see https://www.w3.org/TR/xml/#sec-starttags:

> *Start-tag*
>
> `STag    ::=      '<' Name (S Attribute)* S? '>'`
>
> Tags for Empty Elements
>
> `EmptyElemTag    ::=      '<' Name (S Attribute)* S? '/>'`

Notice the `S?` at the end which optionally allows one or more whitespace characters at the end:

> `S       ::=      (#x20 | #x9 | #xD | #xA)+`

Comment: In other words (to clarify how this answers the question), XML explicitly says that the whitespace in `<something />` is legal, and that a parser that rejects it is therefore non-conforming. (But as avid SO readers will know, there are plenty of people writing home-brew XML parsers who care not a jot about conformance.)