# remove white-space after last attribute before closing tag in xml file

Tags: c#, xml, linq

I need to put data in attributes in xml element, but I don't need this whitespace between `"` and `/>`. How can I remove this whitespace?
`<Organization Name="1" ContractDate="2024-02-27T00:00:00**Z" />`

I used System.Xml.Linq methods:

```
XDocument xdoc = new XDocument();
 XElement organization = new XElement("Organization");
 XAttribute organizationContractDateAttr = new XAttribute("ContractDate", (inputData.OrganizationData.ContractDate).ToString("yyyy-MM-ddT00:00:00Z"));

organization.Add(organizationInnAttr, organizationKppAttr, organizationNameAttr, organizationGozuidAttr, organizationContractDateAttr);
xdoc.Save(path);
```

I tried to use `xdoc.Save(path, SaveOptions.DisableFormatting)` and it transforms whole xml in one string and delete all whitespaces, but I need to delete only whitespace after last attribute.

Example of needed output:   `<Organization Name="1" ContractDate="2024-02-27T00:00:00**Z"/>`
But I get:   `<Organization Name="1" ContractDate="2024-02-27T00:00:00**Z" />`

Comment: Related (not a duplicate) https://stackoverflow.com/q/52064103/125981 as is https://stackoverflow.com/q/13496837/125981 as is https://stackoverflow.com/q/462741/125981 "informational" here

Comment: Possible duplicate https://stackoverflow.com/q/4881564/125981 and https://stackoverflow.com/q/6600902/125981  OR https://stackoverflow.com/q/75169876/125981 - more if you search exist.

Comment: If a particular XML serializer doesn't produce exactly the output you want, you can always try a different serializer. For example, the serializer in SaxonCS will work with LINQ XDocument instances. Generally, though, you should accept that if the serializer is producing a valid XML representation of your data that can be successfully parsed, then it's doing the job it was designed to do.